# AssertionError - when trying to implement new optimizer

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision, pytorch

I am trying to implement new optimizer for my model from [pytorch-optimizer](https://github.com/jettify/pytorch-optimizer) github but when i use i am getting assertion error. i dont know where i am doing wrong

error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-98-44e1eacbb7ce> in <module>()
     69 
     70 p = get_params(OPT_OVER, net, net_input)
---> 71 optimize(OPTIMIZER, p, closure, LR, num_iter)

/content/utils/common_utils.py in optimize(optimizer_type, parameters, closure, LR, num_iter)
    230             optimizer.step()
    231 
--> 232     elif optimizer_type == 'A2GradExp':
    233         print('Starting optimization with A2GradExp')
    234         optimizer = optim.A2GradExp(parameters(), lr=LR)

AssertionError:
```

[image: error]

optimizer code:

```
def optimize(optimizer_type, parameters, closure, LR, num_iter):
    """Runs optimization loop.

    Args:
        optimizer_type: 'LBFGS' of 'adam'
        parameters: list of Tensors to optimize over
        closure: function, that returns loss variable
        LR: learning rate
        num_iter: number of iterations 
    """
    if optimizer_type == 'LBFGS':
        # Do several steps with adam first
        optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(parameters, lr=0.001)
        for j in range(100):
            optimizer.zero_grad()
            closure()
            optimizer.step()

        print('Starting optimization with LBFGS')        
        def closure2():
            optimizer.zero_grad()
            return closure()
        optimizer = torch.optim.LBFGS(parameters, max_iter=num_iter, lr=LR, tolerance_grad=-1, tolerance_change=-1)
        optimizer.step(closure2)

    elif optimizer_type == 'adam':
        print('Starting optimization with ADAM')
        optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(parameters, lr=LR)
        
        for j in range(num_iter):
            optimizer.zero_grad()
            closure()
            optimizer.step()

    elif optimizer_type == 'A2GradExp':
        print('Starting optimization with A2GradExp')
        optimizer = optim.A2GradExp(parameters, lr=LR)
        
        for j in range(num_iter):
            optimizer.zero_grad()
            closure()
            optimizer.step()
    else:
        assert False
```

I have tried other optimizers and my code is working perfectly fine. but when I use one of the optimizer from this link I am getting this error. what are the changes should I make to stop this error.

Comment: You didn't show us what the Assertion Error was or where it occurred.

Comment: I have kept the error. when i am using `A2GradExp` rather than `adam` in the above code i am getting this error. The `A2GradExp` optimizer code i got from -https://github.com/jettify/pytorch-optimizer

Comment: What I'm saying is that you cut off the error listing.  There are more lines after "AssertionError:" that tell us what assertion failed and where.

Comment: I have added the screen shot of the error. i am not getting anything after assertion error

Comment: You probably are going into `else` clause and `optimizer_type` passed as a `str` to the function is different than `LBFGS`, `adam` or `A2GradExp` (make sure you don't have any typos).

Comment: I have tried using other optimizer `ranger` from other github repo its working perfectly fine. i am facing this error when i use optimizer from this github rep. is their any chance that i am implementing this optimizer wrong?

Comment: @harsha please add a line where you __call__ `optimize(optimizer_type, parameters, closure, LR, num_iter)` function.

Comment: @SzymonMaszke you can find the code in the screen shot i attached where i am calling

Comment: @harsha What is the exact value of `OPTIMIZER` you pass as a first argument?

Comment: @SzymonMaszke `OPTIMIZER= 'A2GradExp'`